# Drupal 6 site not displaying image links

Tags: drupal-6

Having a very strange issue which I hope you can help me with.

No errors in Apache logs. I am running a Drupal6 site, with only a few images that are failing to display.

The site's url is configured as a subdomain, i.e. in sites, directory domain.com.insurance contains all the drupal files, modules, etc.

Using Firebug their relative URLs are set to:

```
/insurance/files/webfm/auth/insurance_profiles/profile4.jpg
```

Visiting this file throws a drupal not found page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the URL specified by the developers.

Instead of :

```
/insurance/files/webfm/auth/insurance_profiles/profile4.jpg
```

Correct URL is:

```
/insurance/sites/insurance/files/webfm/auth/insurance_profiles/profile4.jpg
```

Thats it, hope it helps :)